# Daterange picker with datatables, filter date column

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, daterangepicker

Im using the daterangepicker plugin from the followinng link:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

It is working fine within itself but i want to incorporate this within datatables plugin to filter the records by a single date or a range.

I have a date column in datatables which is in the same dateformat as daterangepicker (each record only has a single date).

Does anybody have any ideas of integrating this? Any help/advice would be fantastic, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question should contain relevant code.  I found this looking for a solution, but your link **is now broken**, so this question is very difficult to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9774451/984239) your other version of this question. To summarize:

1. Create datepicker inputs.
2. Copy the date range filter extension from the [filters API page](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering).
3. Give your datepicker inputs the appropriate IDs based on what's in the extension code (or change the extension code to match your datepicker input IDs): `fini` and `ffin` are what the extension uses.
4. In the extension code, specify the zero-based date column(s) that you're using to filter, with `iStartDateCol` and `iEndDateCol`.
5. Bind the table redraw to some event (redraw: `oTable.fnDraw();`).  The example they provide on the API page is a keyup event for the input boxes but it could be a button.

Now whenever the event occurs, the table will redraw taking into consideration the specified date range filtering on the column of choice.