# Adding date range filtering drop down with DataTables

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, filtering, dropdown

I'm trying to add a simple dropdown ("30 days", "60 days", "90 days", "1 year", "All dates") to a DataTables table that will filter the table by the value in the Date column.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773989/datatables-date-filter) answer and understand how to filter by a min and max range entered into text boxes, but can't figure out how to port that to a nice dropdown filter.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a JSFiddle with some example data so we can experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you require but will need some configuration:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof $('#duration').val() !== "undefined") {
      var duration = $('#duration').val();
      var durationBits = duration.split(" ");
      var durationInt = ~~durationBits[0];
      var durationString = durationBits[1];
      var now = moment("2013/08/11", "YYYY/MM/DD");
      var targetDate = now.subtract(durationInt, durationString);
      var iDateCol = 4;
      var colDate = aData[iDateCol];
      if (duration === "All") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return moment(colDate, "YYYY/MM/DD").isSameOrAfter(targetDate);
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
);
```

You'll also need [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to be available. I've got a contrived working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6rjkbok2/). We basically take a date and use `moment` to test whether the date in the column is the same or after the date now with the relevant subtraction having been carried out. We then redraw the table when the select value changes. Hope that helps.